# How to scroll content of a pivot?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a pivot like this on the page:

```
<phone:Pivot Name="pivot">
    <phone:PivotItem Name="item1">
    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

I want to add some images to the item programmatically, so the user can scroll up-down.
When I do this, the scroll viewer doesn't work, I mean doesn't scroll down.

```
    Image image1 = new Image();
    image1.Source = ...

    Image image2 = new Image();
    image2.Source = ...

    Image image3 = new Image();
    image3.Source = ...

    Grid grid2 = new Grid();
    grid2.Children.Add(image1);
    grid2.Children.Add(image2);
    grid2.Children.Add(image3);

    ScrollViewer scroll = new ScrollViewer();
    scroll.Content = grid2;

    item1.Content = scroll;
```

How can I scroll up and down content of the pivot item which is added programmatically? no matter with a `ScrollViewer` or without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first thing I would do is add a listbox to your pivot

```
<phone:Pivot Name="pivot">
    <phone:PivotItem Name="item1">
      <ListBox name="ListOfStuff">
      </ListBox>
    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Then in your cod instead of adding the items to the grid you add them to the listbox.

```
ListOfStuff.Items.Add(ImageWhatever);
```

That should pretty much be it. Your list box will add the items and scroll as normal. Just make sure that the listbox height and width is set to the screen size or smaller. Otherwise your Listbox wont work properly.

You can even get more complicated with this and make nice designs.

Forexample:

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPane();
Image im1 = new Image();
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();

//...Put your sizing and editing of objects here...

sp.orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;


sp.add(im1);
sp.add(tb);

ListOfStuff.Items.Add(sp);
```

This will cause you to have an image with a textblock next to it and it will be a single selectable item in your list.